# MSSQL - How to not allow multiple users to view same set of records

Tags: sql-server, pagination

e.g.
in table I have following records

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

I want to retrieved records by page
say 4 records per page

user x picks

```
a
b
c
d
```

Now user y should not pick any of the above

```
e
f
g
h
```

user x processes a record say record b
now he should see

```
a
e
c
d
```

and user y should see

```
f
g
h
i
```

how can I accomplish this, is there any built in way in mssql?

**UPDATE**
Here's what I have accomplished so far using auxilary table
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e96f1/1

```
AllocateRecords2 2, 5, 1
GO
AllocateRecords2 2, 5, 2
```

both the queries are returning same set of results

Comment: Update the user & status to the row, and fetch rows with certain status / assigned to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use an auxiliary table `UserData`

```
CREATE TABLE Data(
  ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Value varchar(1) NOT NULL
)

INSERT Data(Value)VALUES
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d'),
('e'),
('f'),
('g'),
('h')

-- auxiliary table
CREATE TABLE UserData(
  UserID int NOT NULL,
  DataID int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(UserID,DataID),
FOREIGN KEY(DataID) REFERENCES Data(ID)
)
GO
```

And fill this table using the following procedure

```
CREATE PROC AddDataToUserData
 @UserID int
AS
  INSERT UserData(DataID,UserID)
  SELECT TOP 4 ID,@UserID
  FROM Data d
  WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT DataID FROM UserData)
  ORDER BY ID
GO
```

Execute procedure for each other users

```
--TRUNCATE TABLE UserData

EXEC AddDataToUserData 1
EXEC AddDataToUserData 2
EXEC AddDataToUserData 3
...
```

Select data for a specific user

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Data d
JOIN UserData u ON u.DataID=d.ID
WHERE u.UserID=1

SELECT d.*
FROM Data d
JOIN UserData u ON u.DataID=d.ID
WHERE u.UserID=2
```

You can also create procedure for it

```
CREATE PROC GetDataForUser
 @UserID int
AS
  SELECT d.*
  FROM Data d
  JOIN UserData u ON u.DataID=d.ID
  WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
GO
```

And then use it

```
EXEC GetDataForUser 1
EXEC GetDataForUser 2
```

Hope I understood your question correctly. But if I'm wrong you may use it as an idea.

---

I've added one column `PageNumber` into `AllocatedRecords`

```
/*
DROP TABLE Alphabets
DROP TABLE AllocatedRecords
GO
*/

CREATE TABLE Alphabets
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Record varchar(1)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllocatedRecords](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [ReferenceID] [int] NULL,
    [IsProcessed] [bit] NULL,
    [AllocatedToUser] [int] NULL,
    [AllocatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProcessedDate] [datetime] NULL,
  PageNumber int -- new column
)
GO
INSERT Alphabets VALUES('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g'),('h'),('i'),('j'),('k'),('l'),('m'),('n'),('o'),('p'),('q'),('r'),('s'),('t'),('u'),('v'),('w'),('x'),('y'),('z')
GO
```

And changed your procedure

```
DROP PROC AllocateRecords2
GO

CREATE PROC AllocateRecords2
(
  @UserID INT, 
  @PageSize INT,
  @PageNumber INT
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Today DATETIME
  SET @Today = GETDATE()

  --deallocated expired items
  --TRUNCATE TABLE AllocatedRecords
  DELETE AllocatedRecords
  WHERE IsProcessed = 0 AND
    (
      (DATEDIFF(minute, @Today, AllocatedDate) > 5)
      OR (AllocatedToUser = @UserID AND PageNumber <> @PageNumber)
    )


  DECLARE
    @Draw INT = 10,
    @PoolSize INT = @PageSize,
    @CurrentRecords INT = (SELECT Count(*) from AllocatedRecords WHERE AllocatedToUser = @UserID AND IsProcessed = 0)


  IF @CurrentRecords = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @Draw = @PoolSize
  END
  ELSE IF @CurrentRecords < @PoolSize
  BEGIN
      SET @Draw = @PoolSize - @CurrentRecords
  END
  ELSE IF @CurrentRecords >= @PoolSize
  BEGIN
      SET @Draw = 0
  END

  IF @Draw>0
  BEGIN

    INSERT AllocatedRecords(ReferenceID,IsProcessed,AllocatedToUser,AllocatedDate,ProcessedDate,PageNumber)
      SELECT ID, 0, @UserID, GETDATE(), NULL, @PageNumber
      FROM Alphabets
      WHERE ID NOT IN   (SELECT ReferenceID FROM AllocatedRecords)
    ORDER BY ID
    OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @Draw ROWS ONLY

  END       

  SELECT x.ID, x.Record
  FROM AllocatedRecords A
    JOIN Alphabets x ON A.ReferenceID = x.ID
    WHERE AllocatedToUser = @UserID
    AND IsProcessed = 0

  SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRecords
  FROM AllocatedRecords
  WHERE AllocatedToUser = @UserID
    AND IsProcessed = 0
END
GO
```

Test

```
TRUNCATE TABLE AllocatedRecords
GO

-- user 2
EXEC AllocateRecords2 2, 5, 1
EXEC AllocateRecords2 2, 5, 2
EXEC AllocateRecords2 2, 5, 2 -- the same page

EXEC AllocateRecords2 1, 5, 1 -- user 1
EXEC AllocateRecords2 3, 5, 1 -- user 3
```

Comment: please check updated question, added what i have done

Comment: @NJS - I've modified your code and updated my answer.

Comment: @NJS - I've again modified query for `deallocated expired items`

Comment: @NJS - I think you can delete `@PoolSize` variable and use `@PageSize` instead it.